# Gparted made windows 8 unbootable and unrepairable?

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I resized my windows partition (well technically moved it since I extended the size backwards) and now it is unbootable. Automatic repair is not working, and neither are `bootrec.exe /fixboot` and `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`. I even tried restoring the MBR with Boot Repair and THEN running the previous commands in Windows Repair and yet it still isn't booting

Comment: Since version 0.6.3, GParted has had a warning that moving apartition can break the boot process.  See [Bug 627199 - Warning when moving partition](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627199)

Comment: I know, but what I didn't know is that it could make it irreparable. I have a recovery disk, which doesnt fix it with automatic repair or any cmd commands.

Comment: One of my comments below have more information v

Comment: Did you run chkdsk? Windows has in its partition boot sector the start & size of the NTFS partition. And that must match the partition table. And chkdsk will normally reset that size data.

Answer (score 1):

If you've exhausted all Windows recovery methods available with a startup disk, then it may be that your only choice is to reinstall, but it is possible that all your data is still there, so reinstall windows on the same partition And all uncorrupted data will be in the `C:\windows.old` folder. In my case, I still had everything, nothing was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet is filled with warnings to not do what you did, but you're right that there should be a warning in the program itself. Posting about it here will do no good, though. You may want to [file a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) to get such a warning inserted into GParted.

As to repairing it, I've heard that it can be done, but you're better off asking about that on a Windows forum than here.

Comment: It's not reparable, I had to reinstall, as do many others. Windows recovery disks cannot detect the windows partiton whatsoever after resizing sometimes, which I found few warnings about. I actually saw many tutorials that told it was safe as long as you had a recovery disk, which is obviously untrue As I and many others on a different forum posthave tried every recovery method available with a windows recovery disk. And sadly one of those tutorials was on howtogeek which should probably be removed so nobody else loses their windows partition